# How to make sure that the scripts I package in my War files are in Unix text format?

Tags: eclipse, unix, jakarta-ee

Last day I wrote a script so that my J2ee app could do backups. After deployment, the script was not working. I was wondering why, so I copied it from the deployment directory to my home dir. It was not even executing the first `echo`. That was strange because I tested the script on the very same machine. Later, after another SO question, I discovered that passing it through dos2unix would solve the problem. What happened was that I wrote the script on Linux, I did a simple copy and paste on Eclipse (running on windows), then I deployed the application (and the script was with /n/r the windows way).

How can I avoid this? I mean, I should write the script on Linux and not touch it at all (I'd like to have other options), or is there some special setting I could use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set Eclipse to use Unix line-endings. http://www.sics.se/node/2108

> Navigate to the Workspace preferences
>   (General:Workspace) Change the Text
>   File Encoding to UTF-8 Change the New
>   Text File Line Delimiter to Other and
>   choose Unix from the pick-list Note:
>   to convert the line endings of an
>   existing file, open the file in
>   Eclipse and choose File : Convert Line
>   Delimiters to : Unix